# Ionic Android signed prod app does REST request fails / dead

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, https, ionic3

Not sure what is going on.
When building my app for android 
`ionic cordova run android`

and I manually deploy it to the phone it works well, 
I can track `https` between the device and my backend server.

When I code sign the app

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore appStoreKey.jks ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk MyApp
```

There's no traffic between app and backend. I can not log into the app, it simply does not go beyond the login view and does not allow any traffic outside.

Here's my `config.xml`:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

IMHO this should allow the app to see everything (it's not the default option, only trying to fix this). 
Am I missing something? I even can not debug with Chrome since it has not been built in debug mode. I have no idea what could be going wrong and how to address this issue.

iOS works like a charm both, debug and prod mode.

Comment: this will help https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/http-requests-fails-only-while-releasing-android-build-apk/96356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a feature (or it maybe a bug) in Android Cordova. Based on the top by @AbdulAzeem and [blogpost](http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/) it turns out one has to modify `onReceivedSslError` in `CordovaWebViewClient.java` to enable certificates that are still accepted by iOS. My reasoning is that since Apple puts more emphasis on service & app quality I can live with any certificate that Apple accepts and Cordova fails on. Anyway, the fix as shown in the link still works with Android 9.

Edit

```
platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java
```

ll 237
add comment and code

```
// super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);

// add code
handler.proceed();
return;
```